# IOS get Twitter current Top Trends

Tags: ios, twitter

I want to get Twitter current trends. I tired `https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/get-trendscurrent` but no data does not come. My code is here:

```
-(void) getTwitterTopTrends{

    // 1. Create a variable for twitter
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.json"];

    // 2. Create TWRequest, with parameters, URL & specify GET method
    SLRequest *twitterFeed = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:feedURL parameters:nil];
    twitterFeed.account = _twitterAccount;
    // Making the request
    [twitterFeed performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Check if we reached the reate limit
            if (responseData) {

                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *TWData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
                NSArray* results = TWData [@"trends"];
            }
        });
    }];
}
```

What is my wrong.

Comment: Is error == nil or it holds some info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API version 1 is phased out. Try version 1.1 here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview